# Parse datetimes in apply, returns numeric instead of Date object

Tags: r, date, apply

Maybe I'm over engineering this but I'm building a function for parsing date column automatically depending on the number of columns input.

data:

```
 CreatedDate              LastModifiedDate
 2015-11-20T19:46:11.000Z 2015-11-20T19:46:11.000Z
 2015-11-21T02:54:54.000Z 2015-12-01T18:48:07.000Z
 2015-11-21T14:36:32.000Z 2015-11-21T14:36:32.000Z
 2015-11-21T16:03:41.000Z 2015-11-21T16:03:41.000Z
 2015-11-21T17:31:43.000Z 2015-11-21T17:55:13.000Z




require(lubridate)
require(magrittr

parse_sf_hms <- function(subset) {
  if( is.null( ncol(subset) ) ){
    subset %>% ymd_hms(tz="America/New_York",quiet=TRUE) %>% as.Date(format="%m/%d/%Y") -> x
  return(x)
  } else {
    apply(subset, 2, function(x) x %>% ymd_hms(tz="America/New_York",quiet=TRUE) %>% as.Date(format="%m/%d/%Y") )
  return( x )
  }
}
```

So the issue is that when I use one column (ex. `df[,1]` or `df[,c(CreatedDate)`] ), the function correctly returns:

```
[1] "2015-11-20" "2015-11-21" "2015-11-21" "2015-11-21"
[5] "2015-11-21"
```

But when I use more than one column (ex. `df[,c(1,2)]` or `df[,c('CreatedDate','LastModifiedDate')]`, instead I get:

```
     CreatedDate LastModifiedDate
[1,]       16759            16759
[2,]       16760            16770
[3,]       16760            16760
[4,]       16760            16760
[5,]       16760            16760
```

Why does the single vector correctly returns the date value in format while the apply does not? Would a `lapply`, `rbind` approach better here? 
Just trying to understand the behaviors.

Comment: Don't use `apply(subset, 2, FUN)` as it makes everything a matrix, which coerces your dates back to a numeric. Try `lapply(subset, FUN)` instead.

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail - that answers the most important part of my question about the behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
parse_sf_hms <- function(subset) {
  if( is.null( ncol(subset) ) ){
    subset %>% ymd_hms(tz="America/New_York",quiet=TRUE) %>% as.Date(format="%m/%d/%Y") -> x
    return(x)
  } else {
    x <- lapply(subset, function(x) x %>% ymd_hms(tz="America/New_York",quiet=TRUE) %>% as.Date(format="%m/%d/%Y") )
    return( x )
  }
}
```

As thelatemail said, use lapply.  Also, there is an error in your function.. this:

```
apply(subset, 2, function(x) x %>% ymd_hms(tz="America/New_York",quiet=TRUE) %>% as.Date(format="%m/%d/%Y") )
```

needs to be assigned to `x`:

```
    x <- lapply(subset, function(x) x %>% ymd_hms(tz="America/New_York",quiet=TRUE) %>% as.Date(format="%m/%d/%Y") )
```